# Populate rows based on another table but check if columns exist?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi Guys I'm new here and can really do with your help writing a SQL script/function for the following problem.

I have a `source` table which contains three columns `Name`, `Value`, `miNum`. Example of the data inside this table is:

```
Name      Value      miNum
A+B+C     1+2+3       a1
C+D+E     3+4+5       a3
E+F       5+2         a7
```

Now, I have created a `final_table` and the columns of that table are same as the `source` table but with additional columns labelled a-z (29 columns in total).
What I want the script/Function to do is from the `source` table read each row and populate the corresponding column in `final_table`.

**Example output of `final_table`**

```
Name    Value   miNum    A   B  C  D  E  F
A+B+C   1+2+3    a1      1   2  3  
C+D+E   3+4+5    a3             3  4  5
E+F     5+2      a7                   5  2
```

new columns will be regularly added to the `final_table` so it won't make sense to hard code the columns into the SQL code. Is it possible to do all this without hardcoding column names??

please can someone kindly show me how I can achieve all this.

Thanks

Comment: This is just the wrong way to store data using a relational database.  You are going to need to write a UDF or learn a lot about regular expressions or complex Oracle manipulations to do this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do plan on using a regex with substring function to do the task but my main concern is how can I do this without actually hard coding all columns?

Answer (score 0):

Please add rest of the columns based on this schema:

```
select tst.*, 
case when instr(name,'A') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'A'),1) end A,
case when instr(name,'B') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'B'),1)  end B,
case when instr(name,'C') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'C'),1)  end C,
case when instr(name,'D') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'D'),1)  end D,
case when instr(name,'E') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'E'),1)  end E,
case when instr(name,'F') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'F'),1)  end F
from tst;
```

Gives result

```
NAME   VALUE  MINUM  A B C D E F
------ ------ ------ - - - - - -
A+B+C  1+2+3  a1     1 2 3       
C+D+E  3+4+5  a3         3 4 5   
E+F    5+2    a7             5 2
```

Note that this approach works only for unique names, i.e. for duplicated names only the first value is shown, e.g.

```
NAME   VALUE  MINUM  A B C D E F
------ ------ ------ - - - - - -
A+A+A  5+2+1  a11    5
```

**The other restriction** is that the keys are only `A-Z`  and the values are single character, if this holds you may use this `insert`to populate the target table:

```
Insert into TARGET 
(name, value, miNum,A,B,C,D,E,F)
select name, value, miNum, 
case when instr(name,'A') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'A'),1) end A,
case when instr(name,'B') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'B'),1)  end B,
case when instr(name,'C') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'C'),1)  end C,
case when instr(name,'D') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'D'),1)  end D,
case when instr(name,'E') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'E'),1)  end E,
case when instr(name,'F') > 0 then substr(Value,instr(name,'F'),1)  end F
from source;
```

You will have to extend both insert column list and the query with the column up to `Z`.

Comment: This approach assumes that the values are exactly the same width as the names.

Comment: the width will always be the same.. So if there's 3 characters in name there will always be the same number of values in the value field...
Thanks for all your help so far..
Also, this isn't inserting into the `final_table` from `source`

Comment: @Laura my solution is very restricted, but solves your example data. Please extend the example data if this approach is too limited.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I appreciate your answer. But is the answer looking into `source` table and inserting into `final_table`

Comment: Yes the query is on the `source` and can be used to insert in the `target`. As stated it woks only with key `A-Z` and values with length 1.

Comment: @marmiteBomber.. how do I wrap an insert around this as I wish to take your code but make it insert into my final_table.

Comment: @Laura I added explanation to my answer

Comment: @MarmiteBomber.. Thank you

Comment: @marmiteBomber I ran into a problem. If I have for e.g. A+b+c+ It doesn't work. How can I add in something to remove the extra + at the end?

Comment: try `select trim('+' from '+A+b+c+') from dual` it will remove all leading and trailing plus characters.

Comment: pls consider to  reformulate the question if the answer is not fine, or to accept it:)